# If on excel I have two columns, A e B, how can I have the column C with all the elements of A, that are contents in B?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If on excel I have two columns, A e B, how can I have the column C with all the elements of A, that are contents in B?

[image]

```
Example:

A   B
1   0
2   1
3   9
5   1
       

I would to have a column C: 

C
1
1
```

Thank u!

Comment: `1` will come twice or or only one time?

Comment: two times, cause B have two times 1

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, since there are empty spaces between. You can use `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$5,0)),"",B2)` and drag that formula from `C2` to `C5`

That gives C2 = "", C3 = 1, C4 = "", C5 = 1

[image: https://i.imgur.com/xeFy3MV.png]

Formulas:

[image]

You can sort this column afterwards

Comment: Hi CIAndrews, thank u for ur answer. I dragged that formula from C2 to C5 but it's not working. It is like excel don't use my formula

Comment: I tried this formula too: 
=VLOOKUP($A$2:$A$5;$B$2:$B$5;1;FALSE)
but 1 is counted only 1 time

Comment: @Spicchio, I've added the formulas for columns C

Answer (score 0):

In cell C2, place the following formula:

```
=FILTER(B2:B5,IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B2:B5,A$2:A$5,0)>0,1),0))
```

This creates an array of matches then filters the relevent column for the data